# Javascript function as a variable

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, settimeout, google-tag-manager

I'm a digital analyst and am attempting to learn Javascript, especially as our organization now uses Google Tag Manager.

This morning my site was set to track certain outbound links (clicks to the app store) as events. The custom HTML was:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.app-cta a').click(function(){ 
        dataLayer.push({ 'event':'GAevent', 'eventCategory':'App', 'eventAction':'Click to App Store', 'eventLabel':'iOS' }) 
    }); 

});

</script>
```

But there was an issue (apparently pretty common) where when an individual clicked the exit link, the browser hit the new site before the Javascript had time to pass the parameters to Google Analytics. The suggested workaround was to add a 500 millisecond delay thus:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

setTimeout(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.app-cta a').click(function(){ 
        dataLayer.push({ 'event':'GAevent', 'eventCategory':'App', 'eventAction':'Click to App Store', 'eventLabel':'iOS' }) 
    }); 

});
},500);

</script>
```

This worked which made me feel great because it's the second or 3rd time I'd ever used Javascript.

Then I wanted to be a little bolder. I wanted to make the code "neater" and tried to create a variable out of the analytics function, then run setTimeout method against that variable. This is what I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

setTimeout(function(){track_app},500);


var track_app = $(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('.app-cta a').click(function(){ 
        dataLayer.push({ 'event':'GAevent', 'eventCategory':'App', 'eventAction':'Click to App Store', 'eventLabel':'iOS' }) 
    }); 

});


</script>
```

I realize that this must appear very basic but I'd be grateful if someone could point out why this last attempt did not work? Was my initial attempt (That was working and that I could easily revert to) the "neatest" way of adding the 500 millisecond delay to the analytics function? What would be the best way to integrate the setTimout method?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the workaround actually works? To me it doesn't make sense that you'd add the 500ms delay to the function that pushes the data to Analytics. It would make it even *more* likely to fail.

Comment: @Juhana I cannot explain the logic more fully but yes, it does work.

Comment: setTimeout() is not required here. How's dataLayer.push() implemented?

Comment: @Juhana I just spoke to my buddy. He told me that the setTimeout here actually sets a delay on the outbound link $('.app-cta a'), thus allows 500 milliseconds for the data to transfer

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.

Comment: I might have missed something here, but I don't think that code is right at all. I read it that the 500ms delay is on the code that sets up the link tracking, not that the delay is added to the individual click. I'll add an answer below to show how to do what I think you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it; `track_app` has to be a whole function, not just the function body

```
var track_app = function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.app-cta a').click(function () { 
                dataLayer.push({'event': 'GAevent', 'eventCategory': 'App', 'eventAction': 'Click to App Store', 'eventLabel': 'iOS'});
            });
        });
    };

setTimeout(track_app, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul makes sense I'll remember that

Answer (score 1):

You're basically setting a timeout on a function that executes `track_app`, that is, the return value of the `.ready()` function (whatever that is), not the function itself.

That's why the second iteration of your code is not behaving like the first. You can change  that into:

```
setTimeout(track_app,500);

var track_app = function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.app-cta a').click(function(){ 
            dataLayer.push({ 'event':'GAevent', 'eventCategory':'App', 'eventAction':'Click to App Store', 'eventLabel':'iOS' }) 
        }); 
    });
});
```

EDIT: Paul beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.app-cta a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //do your Google Analytics stuff here

    var href = $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = href;
    }, 500);
});
```

The above is off the top of my head, but the idea is that when someone clicks a link, you stop the browser from naturally following the link (that's the preventDefault method call). Once you've stopped the browser from following the link, you do your GA stuff, then set a timeout to navigate the browser to the link's href attribute.

I don't know GA that well, but I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't something in there already that deals with this scenario - i.e. the browser follows the link before the JS can execute.